# How can I stop Joomla from stripping HTML code from the Contact info?

Tags: joomla

I've only spent maybe 30 mins searching online for this, and couldn't come up with a decent answer.

But anyway, in Joomla there are normal input fields for the Contacts component, but there's a textarea for the Address.

This would make me assume you can enter multiple lines of address in there, and it would be displayed as separate lines... but it doesn't. Even if I enter line breaks, the output is rendered on one line.

So I try to enter `<br>` to separate, and upon saving, Joomla strips these tags out.

In the template, the output is being written simply by echoing `$this->contact->address`

Is there anyway, to explode this input and replace linebreaks with `<br>` marks?

UPDATE:

For now as a temporary measure I'm able to add HTML code into the database values, which saves and outputs on the front end.

On a separate note, I'm now looking to remove the Subject line from the contact form, without hacking the code. and by using overrides as much as possible. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) extension?

Comment: Actually, what I've done is enter '-br-' in the input field where I want the break, and then in the layout file just used a str_replace to replace '-br-' with '<br>'. That works fine.

Comment: @Lee - you should make this the answer and accept it. Great way to do it since I already had an html override in my template for the contact form :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty old, but did you get a solution to this Lee?

To create line-breaks in Joomla, titles, text areas etc. Easiest way to do this is to use the ReReplace extension from NoNumber: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/replace/4336

I personally use this to add line break in e.x. menu-item titles, where < br / > aren't allowed and get stripped.

With ReReplacer, you can create a custom tag e.x. {br} and then have ReReplacer replace {br} with < br / >.

So everytime you need to add a line break anywhere in Joomla, where html codes usually get stripped, you can just add {br} to have it add a new line.

Comment: I did use a method of replacing what I typed, although I didn't use a plugin as it wasn't really needed. I used a str_replace function in php where the address lines are outputted.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I've fallen into the same issue and tried to find a more user friendly solution.

You can enter multiple lines in the address textarea, and they are correctly outputted to the HTML page source. But as you know, newlines in HTML are not rendered, they have to be transformed to `<br>`.

For this PHP has a nice function, `nl2br`, that inserts a `<br>` each time it encounters a newline in a string.

So in `html\com_contact\contact\default_address.php` of your template, replace:

```
echo $this->contact->address;
```

with

```
echo nl2br($this->contact->address);
```

This would nicely do the job, and allow the user to naturally insert any newline in the contact address textarea that will be correctly rendered with the appropriate `<br>`; I believe this is quite more user friendly solution than your previous one of the user having to insert `-br-` tags in the address field.

Comment: This is bad as it'll get overwritten with an update though, won't it?

Comment: It will not get overwritten by an update of Joomla core: I proposed to change it in the template you are using (and if the file is missing, do the override).